# Injecting MongoDB instance in Play Framework [java]

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

Trying to understand how to connect to MongoDB in Play Framework JAVA (version 2.4x)  using built in DI framework, Guice.

So far, I'm using Jongo (version 1.2). I've create a JongoProvider class where I initialise MongoDB instance with relevant ip address to MongoDB, etc.

I inject this into a model like below..., however it seems I can't access the injected instance in a static method. Is there a correct way of accessing inject Mongo object?

```
class User {
    @Inject JongoProvider jongo;

    public static User getUsers() {
        // can't access static instance
        jongo.getcollection("users");
    }
}
```

//=== Edit based on Mon Calamari's answer

```
class User {

    public static JongoProvider jongo() {
        return Play.application().injector().instanceOf(JongoProvider.class);
    }

    public static User getUsers() {
        jongo().getcollection("users");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't use a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `User` does not belong to Guice dependency injection framework, thus you cannot inject Guice dependency into something Guice knows nothing about. Try using static methods on `Play` object:

```
JongoProvider provicer = Play.application().injector().instanceOf(JongoProvider.class)
```

Comment: I mean there is no guice binding for `User` class.